# Pyramid ignores my logging configuration

Tags: python, logging, pyramid

I have a standard logging configuration like:

```
[loggers]
keys = root, quoting, sqlalchemy

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = INFO
handlers = console

[logger_quoting]
level = INFO
handlers =
qualname = quoting

[logger_sqlalchemy]
level = WARN
handlers =
qualname = sqlalchemy.engine
# "level = INFO" logs SQL queries.
# "level = DEBUG" logs SQL queries and results.
# "level = WARN" logs neither.  (Recommended for production systems.)

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s][%(threadName)s] %(message)s
```

And pyramid seems to be ignore it, giving me EVERYTHING on stdout when running with `pserve --reload development.ini`.

Sample log output at http://pastebin.com/1Q3Vt9xM

The log represents one page load. I'm trying to filter out specifically the SQLAlchemy stuff, but would like to know where I went wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `echo=True` on a SQLAlchemy engine configuration will dump to stdout and ignore the logging configuration. This may be what you're seeing.